# Turn off Logging during Release from Nlog.config

Tags: nlog

Now i am doing like this

```
LogManager.DisableLogging();
```

But this need to deploy my code again, how can I disable loggin from nlog configuration file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 <nlog globalThreshold="Off" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help - In the csproj file, you need to add `Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"` where you include `NLog.config` Example:

```xml
<Project>
    ...
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="NLog.config" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>  
    </ItemGroup>
    ...
</Project>
```

This way, in release mode it should not log anything because the NLog.config is not included.